# How can I query Availability Group properties of 'Backup Preferences' using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

We can choose one of the below backup preferences from SSMS.

- Prefer Secondary
- Secondary only
- Primary
- Any Replica

How do I query this '`Backup Preferences`' AG properties through T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

From [Brentozar site](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/how-to-configure-alwayson-ag-backups-with-ola-hallengrens-scripts/):

```
SELECT d.database_name, 
  sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica (d.database_name) AS IsPreferredBackupReplicaNow
FROM sys.availability_databases_cluster d
```

This returns a list of databases in an AG, and whether or not they’re the preferred backup replica right now.

This also seems very usefull  and answers your queries

[image]

For Example ,querying [sys.availability_groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878538.aspx) gives backup preferences..

> Preferred location for performing backups on the availability databases in this availability group. The following are the possible values and their descriptions.
>
> 0 : Primary. Backups should always occur on the primary replica.
>
> 1 : Secondary only. Performing backups on a secondary replica is preferable.
>
> 2 : Prefer Secondary. Performing backups on a secondary replica preferable, but performing backups on the primary replica is acceptable if no secondary replica is available for backup operations. This is the default behavior.
>
> 3 : Any Replica. No preference about whether backups are performed on the primary replica or on a secondary replica.

Comment: But we have four options to choose in the 'Backup Preference'. I would like to know which one of them is checked through T-SQL. 
Say if I choose Backup Preference 'Any Replica' this query will result Zero if I run it on secondary AG.

Comment: Dmvs in screenshot says that